# Rails grouped_collection_select value_method with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Is there any way to use [grouped_collection_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select) `value_method` with parameters in Rails?

I'm trying to filter out a couple of options based on the current_user (effectively using something like: `signed_by(current_user)`) but I'm having some difficulty passing it in.

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :author_id, Author.posts, :signed_by, :title, :id, :email %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to pass parameters to the `value_method` in this case because the `value_method` option is "the name of a method which, when called on a child object of a member of collection, returns a value to be used as the contents of its  tag". In other words, it's just a string or symbol that will get called on the `Author.posts` collection.

If you're trying to filter out some options, I would suggest filtering them from the collection, and then passing the filtered collection to this method. Something like:

```rb
# author_helper.rb
def filtered_author_posts
  Author.posts.where.not(signed_by: current_user)
end
```

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :author_id, filtered_author_posts, :signed_by, :title, :id, :email %>
```